# WPF DataGrid calls BeginEdit on an IEditableObject two times?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ieditableobject

I've got a DataGrid bound to a collection of IEditableObject's.

Now when I click two times in a cell, it will be opened for editing.

Funny thing is: BeginEdit will be called two times. Sometimes for the same EditableObject, but sometimes for two different objects (especially when I use PgDn until I hit the end of the DataGrid) the correct one will be called first, then some other item from the collection, which never had been in focus before.

EndEdit is called twice, too, but always for the selected Item, not for the wrong one.

Is this a known problem? Any workarounds to get only (the right) one notification.

Comment: Sounded interesting so I checked my DataGrid which is also bound to an ObservableCollection<IEditableObject> and did not experience this...? My representation is one object per row, are you by chance merging objects who both implement IEditableObject or something similar?

Comment: Interesting. My object implements only IEditableObject and INotifyPropertyChanged, so there is no merging. My ObservableCollection is wrapped into a custom ListCollectionView, though. And I did bind the Column to a property in a class in my IEditableObject, not directly to a property of the IEditableObject. At least now I got a reason to check my source, thanks!

Comment: The MSDN examples always include a flag that prevents BeginEdit from doing its stuff when called any time but the first. And in my experience, yes it's called multiple times.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace in the debugger when `BeginEdit` is called, you'll see that the first time, it's the collection view calling it, and the second time, it's a `BindingGroup`.

The problem appears to be that there are two things that both think they are in charge of the `IEditableObject` state. When WPF provides a default collection view, it will look for `IEditableObject` on the objects in the collection, and will call `BeginEdit` and either `EndEdit` or `CancelEdit` in response to calls to the corresponding `IEditableCollectionView` methods. But also, the `BindingGroup` will call the `IEditableObject` methods in response to calls to `BeginEdit` and `CommitEdit` or `CancelEdit`.

The `DataGrid` uses both features: when you start and complete edits in a row, it notifies the `IEditableCollectionView` *and* the `BindingGroup` and both of those things think that it's their responsibility in turn to go on and notify the `IEditableObject` implementation on the underlying source object.

So it looks rather like a bug in the `DataGrid` - it causes two different objects to call `BeginEdit` (and related methods). And it's because it makes use of editable collection views and binding groups - from the look of it, those weren't designed to be used at the same time on the same objects, in the way that the `DataGrid` uses them.

The reason you don't see this problem with the grid in the Toolkit is that it appears to be a slightly older version - comparing the code in that with what Reflector shows for .NET 4.0, you'll see that the .NET 4.0 `DataGrid` has some extra code (a new method, `EnsureItemBindingGroup`, and some related code in `MeasureOverride` and `OnRowValidationRulesChanged`) that ensures that a binding group always exists, whether you ask for it or not. So if the WPF Toolkit is updated, it'll probably grow a similar feature unless this gets fixed. (And I would guess that if you use the current edition - February 2010 as I write this - of the WPF Toolkit, and you use the `ItemBindingGroup` property to ask explicitly for a binding group, you'd see exactly the same problem.)

This doesn't explain how you'd get calls to `BeginEdit` on random objects as you've described. I can't repro that. But it does explain double calls on the selected object. The best thing to do appears to be to code your source objects so that they will tolerate the double calls.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you'd use to interrupt the BeginEdit event before it happens, but for EndEdit a simple isDirty marker will do. In your Entity class that implements IEditableObject, add the following:

```
    private bool _isDirty = false;

    #region IEditableObject Members

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        // Bug Fix: Windows Controls call EndEdit twice; Once
        // from IEditableCollectionView, and once from BindingGroup.
        // This makes sure it only happens once after a BeginEdit.
        _isDirty = true;
    }

    public void CancelEdit() { }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        if (ItemEndEdit != null && _isDirty)
        {
            _isDirty = false;
            ItemEndEdit(this);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: You should set _isDirty=false in CancelEdit method.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem using .NET Framework 4 DataGrid.

Add Reference to last version of WPFToolkit

Add

```
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

and change `<DataGrid>` with `<dg:DataGrid>`

Comment: Cool, and Interesting. Is this a different version, or why does this fix the problem??

Answer (score 1):

+1 @IanGriffiths for diagonsing the Problem.  As for a solution (or workaround rather), you can count the number of "pending" Edits.  That means something like:

```
void BeginEdit()
{
    _numEdits++;
}

void CancelEdit()
{
    if(--_numEdits < 0)
        throw new Exception("WTF?"); 
}

void EndEdit()
{
    CancelEdit();
    if(_numEdits == 0)
        commitEdit();
}
```