# Event notification after a DataGrid row has been editted and data committed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way I can receive a notification *after* a WPF DataGrid row has been edited and the changes committed to the underlying object? At this point I want to persist the modified item to disk.

I don't need to know which row was modified, I can find that out myself, I just need the notification that a row has been modified.

I could register a PropertyChanged handler with each object in the model and be notified that way, but apart from having to mess around registering/deregistering event handlers whenever items are added/removed from the collection, a bigger problem is how to handle multiple PropertyChanged events being raised on a row edit. I don't want to be saving the item multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing the [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, which was created for just this purpose.  The grid will call `EndEdit` when the row is done being modified, which I believe is when the row loses focus.

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450878/wpf-datagrid-calls-beginedit-on-an-ieditableobject-two-times) for more information on how the grid interacts with this interface.

I would recommend implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` anyway if you plan on updating the grid on a refresh, or otherwise editing values in code.  If you want to do updates immediately on a cell update, you could also do it in the property changed handler.