# Writing an EventTrigger for WPF DataGridRow

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, eventtrigger

I want to write a Trigger on a WPF DataGridRow as follows-

When user makes any change in any cell of that row, the last cell of same row should be updated by some specific value.

Please help....

Comment: Is that last column is specified?In another word the property bound in the last colum is fixed or various?

Comment: the last column is bound to the same Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the solution provided by **Brian Hinchey** at the following link- [How to get property change notifications with EF 4.x DbContext generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010718/how-to-get-property-change-notifications-with-ef-4-x-dbcontext-generator/12192358#12192358)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done with a trigger.

For an MVVM-based solution you could change your entity to implement `IEditableObject`. When you commit a cell change in the DataGrid (e.g. tabbing off or pressing Enter), the entity's `IEditableObject.EndEdit()` method will get called. You could then update your last cell's bound property in there.

(For some reason `EndEdit()` is called twice, which appears to be a quirk/bug when using IEditableObject with DataGrids. The problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450878/wpf-datagrid-calls-beginedit-on-an-ieditableobject-two-times)).

If you want more control of if/when `IEditableObject.EndEdit()` gets called, you can use the DataGrid RowEditEnding and CellEditEnding events. E.g. the following `RowEditEnding` event handler code will ensure that the entity's EndEdit() method gets called only when you commit an entire row (rather than after each cell commit):-

```
    private void RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isCommittingEdit || e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            _isCommittingEdit = true;
            try
            {
                grid1.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isCommittingEdit = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've found that calling `DataGrid.CommitEdit()` causes the same event to fire again, resulting in a stack overflow, hence the `_isCommittingEdit` variable to stop this from happening. (I would be interested to know if it's another quirk or something that I'm doing wrong!)

Comment: What i feel is that, here we don't need to use  grid1.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);                                                                                 I achieved the same using the following code-                         private void DgTeam_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_context.Entry((Team)e.Row.Item).State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                ((Team)e.Row.Item).Mode = "E";
      
            }
        }   but i am trying to find out whetehr this can be done using xaml

Comment: I think this is a little too complicated to be achieved with a trigger. Sometimes you have to resort to a code-behind event handler! If you are using MVVM and are concerned about putting business logic in code-behind, it could call a method on the VM to set the last column value (assuming you are using "view-first", i.e. the view has a reference to the VM).